# Custom Attribute with optional parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes

I have this Custom Attribute (Custom MVC Authorization):

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public string Users { get; set; } //its always null!

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        string user = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];

        AdProxy AdProxy = new AdProxy();

        if (!AdProxy.IsUserInGroup(user, Users))
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);

        }
    }

}
```

I use it like this:

```
[CustomAuthorizeAttribute(Users = "Admin")]
```

But on debugging the value of "Users" is always null. 
Any idea?

Comment: First I think that you forget that Users in your class is not base.Users. Probably you are missing the constructor with [optional parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) which overrides the base.Users property or just fill it through your parent constructor.

Comment: What do you mean? can you write the ctor plz? According to this link: http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/G54G220114-Custom-Authentication-and-Authorization-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html I dont have to add a ctor and fill the parameters

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .net Framework 4.5.1 change to 4.5 and it should work.

```
class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string Users { get; set; }
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
 { ... }
```

Comment: It should work now. There was misspell in AuthorizeAttribute - There is no AuthorizationFilterAttribute. Only Authorize attribute which contains in itself Users property.